# Removing duplicate rows based on most recent entry

Tags: r

I apologize as I know variations of this question has been asked before, but I tried to reach the answers provided and couldn't apply it to my data.

I have the following data from survey results. Several people completed surveys for various webinars they attended. A person may have completed more than one survey if they attended more than one webinar. I'd like to keep only the latest survey result from each person (i.e., remove duplicates but keep the most recent survey submission based on "Date Survey Submitted" column).

Sample Current Data:

```
Name <- c("John", "Sara", "Nakita", "John", "Raj")
Webinar Code <- c(4, 4, 4, 2, 4)
Date Survey Submitted <- c("1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/15/20", "1/1/20")
```

Desired Result:

```
Name <- c("Sara", "Nakita", "John", "Raj")
Webinar Code <- c(4, 4, 2, 4)    
Date Survey Submitted <- c("1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/15/20", "1/1/20")
```

I'm limited in my knowledge of R, but have been using the distinct() function to remove duplicate rows til now. But I don't know how to add a conditional to keep the row with the most recent date. I'm hoping to find a solution that isn't too complicated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can first `arrange(Date)` and then `distinct()`. I'm not sure how dates are sorted but I would try `arrange(desc(Date))` for descending order. Make sure the dates are actual Dates rather than normal strings using `as.Date()` or they'll sort wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class of `DateSurveySubmitted` to date, `arrange` the data based on date in descending order and select the first row for each `Name`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DateSurveySubmitted = as.Date(DateSurveySubmitted, '%m/%d/%y')) %>%
  arrange(Name, desc(DateSurveySubmitted)) %>%
  distinct(Name, .keep_all = TRUE)

#    Name WebinarCode DateSurveySubmitted
#1   John           2          2020-01-15
#2 Nakita           4          2020-01-01
#3    Raj           4          2020-01-01
#4   Sara           4          2020-01-01
```

Or using `group_by` and select the max row for each `Name`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(DateSurveySubmitted = as.Date(DateSurveySubmitted, '%m/%d/%y')) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  slice(which.max(DateSurveySubmitted)) %>%
  ungroup
```

**data**

```
Name <- c("John", "Sara", "Nakita", "John", "Raj")
WebinarCode <- c(4, 4, 4, 2, 4)
DateSurveySubmitted <- c("1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/15/20", "1/1/20")
df <- data.frame(Name, WebinarCode, DateSurveySubmitted)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application of `dplyr::slice_max`

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(Name = c("John", "Sara", "Nakita", "John", "Raj"),
           Webinar_Code = c(4, 4, 4, 2, 4),
           Date_Survey_Submitted = c("1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/1/20", "1/15/20", "1/1/20"))

dat %>% 
  mutate(Date_Survey_Submitted = as.Date(Date_Survey_Submitted, "%m/%d/%y")) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  slice_max(order_by = Date_Survey_Submitted, n = 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   Name [4]
#>   Name   Webinar_Code Date_Survey_Submitted
#>   <chr>         <dbl> <date>               
#> 1 John              2 2020-01-15           
#> 2 Nakita            4 2020-01-01           
#> 3 Raj               4 2020-01-01           
#> 4 Sara              4 2020-01-01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the ordering, then you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
dat %>%
  rownames_to_column("id") %>%
  arrange(desc(myd(Date_Survey_Submitted))) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(Name)) %>%
  arrange(id)%>%
  select(names(dat))

    Name Webinar_Code Date_Survey_Submitted
1   Sara            4                1/1/20
2 Nakita            4                1/1/20
3   John            2               1/15/20
4    Raj            4                1/1/20
```